# Convert arrays with object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
{"result":[{"id":1,"currency":"USD"},{"id":2,"currency":"PLN"},{"id":3,"currency":"EUR"}],"success":true}
```

I would like to have array with only id:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's a tonne of questions like this already on Stack Overflow. With minimal research, at least one of them will have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. You should show us what you have tried so far and what you want to achieve.

Comment: `result` is an array, so you'll want to start with understanding how to loop over that. MDN is [always a good place to start with understanding JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: `obj.result.map(a => a.id)`

Comment: In easier way, for proper understanding   
```let obj = {"result":[{"id":1,"currency":"USD"},{"id":2,"currency":"PLN"},{"id":3,"currency":"EUR"}],"success":true}
let arr = []
obj.result.forEach(element => {
    arr.push(element.id)
});
console.log(arr)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with `array#map`

```js
var arr = {"result":[{"id":1,"currency":"USD"},{"id":2,"currency":"PLN"},{"id":3,"currency":"EUR"}],"success":true};

console.log(arr['result'].map(a=>a.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {result":[{"id":1,"currency":"USD"},{"id":2,"currency":"PLN"},{"id":3,"currency":"EUR"}],"success":true};

let ids = data.result.map(item => item.id);
```

Here it works